# Cannot connect UIButton to ViewController in XCode4

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ibaction, iboutlet

I'm learning iPhone Dev and I'm stuck on something. I'm writing a simple calculator program, but when I try to connect one of the buttons on the calculator to the File Owner in Interface Builder I do not get any options:

.h file

```
@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController
{

    CalculatorBrain *brain;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;

}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

- (IBAction)operandPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"

@implementation CalculatorViewController

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //not implemented yet
}

- (IBAction)operandPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //not implemented yet
}
@end
```

As far as I understand when I'm working with my CalculatorViewController.xib in interface builder if I try to connect a button to the file's owner I should have two options:
1. digitPressed
2. operandPressed

However, I do not get any options. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try changing `(UIButton *)sender` to just `(id)sender`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Check that file's owner is set to CalculatorViewController
- In IB, click the button, then click the option on the far right (connections, I think it is called)
- Find the action called touchUpInside. Drag from the circle next to this to your files owner, the two actions will pop up then.

Comment: *"You can't go directly from the button, you need to specify which type of touch event is linked to the action."* - Yes you can, it defaults to `touchUpInside`.

Comment: Sorry, you've already said it's v4. Can you give more detail than "not working?"

Comment: I cannot drag an outlet from my button to the file owner's.

Comment: So, the dragging line doesn't appear, or you cant drop the end of it on files owner?

Comment: @jrturton tkx for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Are you dragging from the button to the owner or the other way around?

If you want to refer to an object in a nib from code, then you define an `IBOutlet` and drag from the owner to the object.

If you want to refer to code from an object in a nib file, then you define an `IBAction` and drag from the object to the owner.

Comment: I'm dragging from the button to the file owner's

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue.
The problem was that I renamed the ViewController. 
The XIB file has the name of the view controller inside of it.

when it doesn't match the actual name of the UI View Controller class interface builder will act funny.

To fix it, open the XIB file as source code (right click it and use Open As source code)
it's an XML file. find the name of the old controller and then change it to the correct name.
I found it in the XML under:

```
<dictionary class="NSMutableDictionary" key="flattenedProperties">
    <string key="-1.CustomClassName">xxxxxxViewController</string>
```